# Best workaround for not being able to inherit a sealed class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, fileinfo, sealed

I am making a program that processes thousands of files. For each file I create a FileInfo instance, but I am missing some methods and properties that I need.

I wanted to make my own custom FileInfo class by inherting from FileInfo, but that class is sealed so I can't.

I considered making extension methods for FileInfo, but that seems ugly and it requires me to run the same code multiple times while processing.
So instead I came up with a custom class that 'wraps' the FileInfo class.

Here's a part of it:

```
class MyFileInfo
{
    FileInfo _fileInfo;

    // wrapper of existing property
    public string Name { get { return _fileInfo.Name; } }

    // custom property
    public string NameWithoutExtension { get; private set; }

    // custom property
    public string Increment { get; private set; }

    public MyFileInfo(string filePath)
    {
        _fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

        NameWithoutExtension = GetNameWithoutExtension();
        Increment = GetIncrement();
    }

    private string GetNameWithoutExtension()
    {
        return _fileInfo.Name.Replace(_fileInfo.Extension, string.Empty);
    }

    private string GetIncrement()
    {
        return Regex.Match(NameWithoutExtension, @" #?\d{1,4}$").Value;
    }
}
```

Now my question is: is this the best way to do this? How else could one work around not being able to inherit a sealed class?

Comment: Can you explain the problem you had with extension methods?

Comment: With extension methods I would call them multiple times, thus running the same code multiple times. Whereas if I have a class I can do all I need to do and set the custom properties only once in the constructor, which seems more efficient.

Comment: Makes sense, if it's happening enough that there's noticeable overhead. Incidentally, there's a [`Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8), which will be safer and likely faster than what you've got there. In answer to (what I think is) the meat of your question: What you're doing looks to me like a sensible way to trade memory for cycles, but when you're optimizing, profile everything to be sure you're attacking the real problem and doing so effectively.

Answer (score 2):

You have done it almost right, The solution to your problem is exactly the use of [`decorator pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

> The decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows the behavior to be
>   added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically,
>   without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.

Check these posts for more details:

1- [UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp)

2- [benefiting-with-the-decorator-pattern](http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/benefiting-with-the-decorator-pattern/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I understand the decorator pattern now but I'm not sure yet why I should use this over the solution I put above.

With the decorator I would make one or more new classes with the functionality I want to add and then chain them in the instantiating of FileInfo right?

So for example:
`FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo().ExtensionClass()`